# cambiar mensaje de instrucciones de uso de google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

[image: Google maps]

Como cambiar ese mensaje de texto (cuadro rojo) de goolge maps por uno personalizado para mis mapas, gracias.

Comment: Hey Jairo, bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usando un div instrucciones hice el efecto yo mismo - gracias por sus comentarios.

## instructions {

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: gray;
opacity: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
pointer-events: none;//<-------- esto resolvió mi problema que capturaba 
//el div en lugar del mapa antes de tener esta instrucción
animation: fadein 15s;
```

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0.7; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Usar jquery para hacerlo usando este codigo:

```
$('.gm-style-pbt').text('Texto de ejemplo')
```

O bien puedes hacerlo mediante Código nativo:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gm-style-pbt')[0].innerHTML = 'Texto Ejemplo'
```

Comment: no funciona para mi